# Having one subreport bigger than the other subreport creates white space in the main report

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, removing-whitespace, subreports

In my main report, I have 3 sub reports that have data and can grow to different sizes because the size of the data isn't consistently the same, they mainly in change in height though. When the sub reports are of the same size, the main report looks fine but when one sub report has one more row than the others, it results in a white space that I'd like to get rid of.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You think we can help you with the amount of information you provided?

Comment: What do you want to replace the white space with? I'm not sure what you can do when there are more rows in one that the other table other than limiting the numbers of rows to be even.

Comment: I forgot to mention that rows have alternating background color fills so if I am able to replace the white space with the appropriate fill then that would be perfect.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is to have the query for each subreport count the records for the other dataset and spoof blank rows for the dataset that has fewer records. Maybe put the results in a temp table, figure out how many rows to add then add a loop to add a blank record to the temp table. Seems like a bit of work though.